# How to connect dots in order in a scatter plot?

Tags: python, scatter-plot, line-plot

I want to connect some points to understand the shape of the data. My code is the following

```py
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from random import randint, uniform,random
import random
import math

FO_1_NSGA=[1737903,1775238,1745292,1753900,1739432,1765932]
FO_2_NSGA=[1250000,1212665,1235970,1224003,1242687,1216719]
plt.scatter(FO_1_NSGA,FO_2_NSGA,marker='s',c="red",linewidths=True,label="NSGA",edgecolors='blue')
plt.plot(FO_1_NSGA,FO_2_NSGA)
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel("Costo Total de Transporte (CTT)")
plt.ylabel("Costo Total por Demanda Insatisfecha (CDIT)")
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.show()
```

The output is the following (which is right)

[image]

I want to connect these points to see the exponential decreasing behavior of my variables, but when I try to do that adding the following code

```py
plt.plot(FO_1_NSGA,FO_2_NSGA)
```

I get this
[image]

which is clearly not right... any ideas?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your datasets are not in ascending or descending order, you need to make sure that when using plt.plot, you have the x-variable in ascending order with the corresponding y-variable in the respective positions. This is because plt.plot will join the dots in the order that it is given, so one must provide the data points in an ascending or descending order.

Reformat the datasets to:

F0_1_NSGA = [1737903, 1739432, 1745292, 1753900, 1765932, 1775238]

F0_2_NSGA = [1212665, 1216719, 1224003, 1235970, 1242687, 1250000]

This will ensure that both your plt.plot and plt.scatter have the same graph shape.

Hope that worked :)

Comment: Thanks. How can I do that?

Comment: Reformat the datasets to:

F0_1_NSGA = [1737903, 1739432, 1745292, 1753900, 1765932, 1775238]

F0_2_NSGA = [1212665, 1216719, 1224003, 1235970, 1242687, 1250000]

This will ensure that both your plt.plot and plt.scatter have the same graph shape.

Comment: And there is a way to do that coding?

Comment: That is the way, you just have to rearrange the order of the values in each of your datasets, which I have done for you(I edited my answer). Just copy the lines that I have and replace it with the ones that you had.